# how can i go to button_Click event with url of ajax?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, events, asp.net-ajax

i want to go  by ajax .

my html code:

```
   <a href="#" id="DeleteNews"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-2x borderd" ></i></a>
```

my javascript code:

```
bootbox.dialog({
        title: 'Delete News',
        message: 'Are you sure?',
        buttons: {

            submit: {
                label: "Accept",
                className: "btn-primary btn-sm",
                callback: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'News.aspx/DeleteNews_Click',
                        //type: 'post',
                        success: function () {
                            bootbox.alert("Deleted!", function () {
                                location.href = 'News.aspx';

                            });

                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            cancel: {
                label: "Cancel",
                className: "btn-default btn-sm"
            }
        }
    });
```

my event code in News.aspx.cs:

```
 protected void DeleteNews_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //some codes...
    }
```

but it doesn't go to DeleteNews_Click.
what should i do?
Thanks

Comment: You need to make a WebMethod. WebMethods need to be static and public in order to be accessible with Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a delete control on your page like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" OnClick="Delete_Click" style="display:none" />
<a href="#" id="DeleteNews"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-2x borderd" ></i></a>
```

Then you could call the code behind like this way:

```
$(document).on("click", "#DeleteNews", function (e) {
    bootbox.dialog({
        title: 'Delete News',
        message: 'Are you sure?',
        buttons: {

            submit: {
                label: "Accept",
                className: "btn-primary btn-sm",
                callback: function () {
                    document.getElementById('<%: Delete.ID %>').click();
                }
            },
            cancel: {
                label: "Cancel",
                className: "btn-default btn-sm"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and in your code behind you could display the success message when the news has deleted successfully:

```
protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // delete the news here

    if(result == success){
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), 
                                            "SuccessMessage", 
                                            @"bootbox.alert('Deleted!', 
                                                            function () { 
                                                                location.href = 'News.aspx'; 
                                                            });", true);
    }
}
```